# What's the difference between using Url.Content and not doing so?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm following a [blog tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/using-fullcalendar-jquery-component-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) to implement the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)-plugin called [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), into an ASP.NET-project.

In that tutorial, they claim the following:

> Url.Content method creates correct URL-s and it is way better than MS strategy (href like ....\Content\Site.css).

But they don't even attempt to explain how they've come to that conclusion.

---

So what's the difference between this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4414271/122005 may help for your question.

Comment: I can see that the question is basically the same, but I don't understand the answer.

Comment: The explanation provided in that answer I believe comes closer to outlining the difference; Url.Content method ensures the path is always correct with routing. However, for paths starting with "~", it will translate the url to the correct, application relative url, e.g., <%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/SomeScript.js")%> could translate to /MyVirtualDirectory/Scripts/SomeScript.js, if you deployed your web application to a virtual directory MyVirtualDirectory below the root folder of the web site.

Comment: I thought HTML also had a relative path possibility, judging from your comments and hunter's answer I'm thinking it doesn't, and that was the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"`

That above will not resolve to a url since `~/` doesn't mean anything to the browser

`"<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>"`

`Url.Content` will resolve the path of the url specified after `~/` in your application

---

**UrlHelper.Content Method**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.108).aspx

```
Converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.
```

Comment: So relative paths are not possible without Url.Content?

Comment: Relative path is not the same thing as dynamic path. "/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" is a relative path and will work IF your application is at the root of the domain (http://mysite.com/). However, if you end up with http://mysite.com/foo/ as you application root, then you would have to change the path to "/foo/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js". This is where the UrlHelper comes in handy. It will replace that "~" to "/foo".